# Multicollinearity of Socioeconomic index vs. wealth variables separately?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, multicollinearity, cox-model

I am running Cox regressions in a large dataset to determine effects of individual and area characteristics on mortality outcomes. (My model is not a multilevel model, as the initial significant variation (random intercepts) between areas disappeared once SES variables have been adjusted for).

I have three categorical individual level socio-economic measures (car ownership, housing tenure, and education). These can be used to construct a socioeconomic index with a scale of 0-7 (based on their categories). On the area level, I have a "morbidity" variable, which is the proportion of adults with an illness in the area.

When using the socioeconomic variables on their own—i.e. not as an index—they are not correlated with each other, nor with area illness. However, the individual SES index aggregated on area level is highly correlated to area illness (0.78). Can I put in the three SES measures separately (not as an index) and the area level measure for illness in the same model, or is that problematic?

Many thanks!

Edit: I share your view that multilevel models are important to estimate the variance. However, a few things make me think I it might be ok to go with a non-MLM model in this case.

To give a bit more info on my analysis: I have approximately 500 000 individuals clustered in 571 wards. I’m examining a variety of mortality outcomes, some of which are quite rare, which means I do not have a death/event in every ward during my follow up period. I think I need at least one event in every level 2 unit (in this case ward) unit to run a MLM (or Cox survival analysis with shared frailty)?

Due to the large sample size Cox models with shared frailty (in Stata 12) take a very long time to run. Run instead with Streg my theta is 0.008 (st err 0.01) when all individual level factors (SES, age, family etc) are controlled for. I relatively new to survival analyses with shared frailty and haven’t come across a good explanation on how to interpret theta. IS it the same as level 2 variance estimated e.g. in a normal multi-level model in MlwiN or R?  Any help here appreciated!

I interpret this as when demographic and socioeconomic factors explain any variation between wards in risk of death. AIC for models without shared frailty (by ward) are lower than models without (of at least 2, often more).

With this information in mind, would you still advice me to run models with shared frailty?

Thank you again!

Comment: I think you still need a multi-level model. It will affect estimation of the variances.